# Cannot stub function call in imported file with Sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to assert that the `trackPushNotification` is being called inside my `notifier.send` function. **Both the trackPushNotification and send function live inside the same file.**
I assumed I should stub the `trackPushNotification` using Sinon to be able to keep track of the `callCount` property. When I execute my test, the `trackPushNotification` doesn't seem to get stubbed at all. I've searched some things and apparently it has something to do with the way I'm using ES6 import/exports. I couldn't find an answer so I hope someone can help me with this issue.

The `notifier.send` function looks like this:

```
export const send = (users, notification) => {
  // some other logic

  users.forEach(user => trackPushNotification(notification, user));
};
```

My `notifier.trackPushNotification` function looks like this:

```
export const trackPushNotification = (notification, user) => {
  return Analytics.track({ name: 'Push Notification Sent', data: notification.data }, user);
};
```

My test case looks like this:

```
it('should track the push notifications', () => {
  sinon.stub(notifier, 'trackPushNotification');

  const notificationStub = {
    text: 'Foo notification text',
    data: { id: '1', type: 'foo', track_id: 'foo_track_id' },
  };

  const users = [{
    username: 'baz@foo.com',
  }, {
    username: 'john@foo.com',
  }];

  notifier.send(users, notificationStub);

  assert.equal(notifier.trackPushNotification.callCount, 2);
});
```

Also did a quick test:

```
// implementation.js
export const baz = (num) => {
  console.log(`blabla-${num}`);
};

export const foo = (array) => {
  return array.forEach(baz);
};

// test.js
it('test', () => {
  sinon.stub(notifier, 'baz').returns(() => console.log('hoi'));

  notifier.foo([1, 2, 3]); // outputs the blabla console logs

  assert.equal(notifier.baz.callCount, 3);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way you can test it. Please notice that you need the **this** statement when calling trackPushNotification

## module:

```
class notificationSender {
    send(users, notification){        

        users.forEach(user => this.trackPushNotification(notification, user));        
    }

    trackPushNotification(notification, user){
        console.log("some");
    }

}


 export default notificationSender;
```

## import on test

```
import notificationSender from './yourModuleName';<br/>
```

## test

```
    it('notifications', function(){
        let n = new notificationSender();        
        sinon.spy(n,'trackPushNotification');

        n.send(['u1','u2'],'n1');
        expect(n.trackPushNotification.called).to.be.true;

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, the hint with adding `this` when calling the function did the trick for me, without it the sinon seems not to find the method it should stub :)